# Reference request for Newton's method on a convex/concave function

Tags: newton-raphson

The proof featured at http://planetmath.org/newtonsmethodworksforconvexrealfunctions shows that, roughly speaking, *Newton's method* is **unconditionally convergent for convex/concave functions**.

I am looking for a textbook or paper reference of this fact. I have found part of it in Michael Spivak's Calculus: [image]

Comment: You could look at the textbook Convex Optimization, by Boyd and Vandenberghe which is free online.

Comment: I do not think there will be much there, as Boyd is interested in maximizing $f$, and hence he will try to find roots of $f^\prime$ (using quasi-Newton methods). However, $f^\prime$ is not necessarily convex/concave whenever $f$ is.

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't understand your question when I posted that comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not found any references from books, but the cached version of a PlanetMath page (currently down) captures all of the relevant cases (attached). I am posting it to answer the question for other readers.

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]
[image: page 3]